# Overriding portlet templates with z3c.jbot

Tags: plone

Is it possible? Do portlet renderers satisfy necessary conditions for z3c.jbot to kick in?

If so... what's the correct syntax to refer portlet renderer via z3c.jbot filename?

Comment: Looks like it is possible... and nothing special is needed.

Comment: So, why didn't you try it before asking the question? :-P

Comment: I tried... failed! Apparently had issue with templates/ folder in the path.

Comment: @Mikko, I'm glad you asked the question. Now the solution is recorded on stackoverflow for others (like me) to benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, it's possible.

The filename is just the package name plus the original template file name, just like other z3c.jbot files. For example, the `manage-contextual.pt` template in `plone.app.portlets.browser.templates` becomes `plone.app.portlets.browser.templates.manage-contextual.pt` to override the original.